# If statement checks the global var but runs both conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm banging my head to the wall, please help :(

EDIT: The script works on jsfiddle, my own server, but on client's server not :/

I have a simple price switcher based on global variable. I want to use the global var, because the switcher contains: text ie. Discount on (clickable), styled checkbox (with colors), text (clickable) ie. Discount off - so I can add listeners to clickable `span` elements with texts and change the color etc. of the styled `checkbox`.

Code for discount button:

```
<p class="prices-starter-switch">
<span class="prices-starter-discount active">Prices with discount</span>
<label id="pricesSwitcher" class="switch"><input type="checkbox" checked>
<span class="slider round"></span></label>
<span class="prices-starter-discount-none">Prices without discount</span>
</p>
```

The price elements are construced like this:

```
<em data-normalprice="52" data-discountedprice="47" class="price-to-add-discount">47</em>
<em data-normalprice="60" data-discountedprice="54" class="price-to-add-discount">54</em>
<em data-normalprice="100" data-discountedprice="90" class="price-to-add-discount">90</em>
```

`data-normalprice` and `data-discountedprice` hold the prices value to be swapped in the `em` element.

The prices are listed in two ways - normal listing and table at the bottom of the page. All the prices to be switched (normal price and discounted) have class `price-to-add-discount`

On the backend, I'm displaying the discounted price when the page loads.

I'd like to use global var to change all the prices (as `em's` and inside `table`).

I wrote the code, but when firing the listener on click the `if` statement goes all the way and don't  check the conditions :/

Here's the JS code:

```
window.pricesSetToDiscounted = true;
// I'm setting the global var to true, since from the backend side I'm showing the client the discounted prices
as he load's the website
window.prices_to_be_calculated = document.querySelectorAll(".price-to-add-discount");
// selecting all the elements with prices to work with

var btn = document.getElementById('pricesSwitcher'); // my simple button ID

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(typeof pricesSetToDiscounted != 'undefined' && pricesSetToDiscounted==true) {
       pricesShowNormal();
   }
    else if(typeof pricesSetToDiscounted != 'undefined' && pricesSetToDiscounted==false) {
        pricesShowDiscounted();
    }
}, false);

function pricesShowDiscounted() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < prices_to_be_calculated.length; i++) {
        var discountedPrice = prices_to_be_calculated[i].dataset.discountedprice;
        prices_to_be_calculated[i].innerHTML = discountedPrice;     }
    pricesSetToDiscounted = true;
    console.log("pricesSetToDiscounted has value: "+pricesSetToDiscounted);
};

function pricesShowNormal() {
    var y;
    for (y = 0; y < prices_to_be_calculated.length; y++) {
        var normalPrice = prices_to_be_calculated[y].dataset.normalprice;
        prices_to_be_calculated[y].innerHTML = normalPrice;
    }
    pricesSetToDiscounted = false;
    console.log("pricesSetToDiscounted has value: "+pricesSetToDiscounted);
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you try to achieve, but for me your code is working.
I've made a quick [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcq0bnjs/).

Comment: It *cannot* execute both branches of an `if..else` *in the same go.* Most likely your click event is being triggered again…!

Comment: @Nerdkowski - it works on jsfiddle, on live server doesn't... the `if..else` runs without looking at conditions :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
document.getElementById('prices-switcher').onclick = function() {
    if (pricesSetToDiscounted == true) {
        pricesShowNormal();
    } else {
        pricesShowDiscounted();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Works like a charm - both on jsfiddle, my server and client's server :)